# Prove the roots of these exponential functions are integers?

Tags: exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, roots, special-functions

The zeros of $3^x-2^x$ is 0.

The zeroes of $4^x-2\cdot3^x+2^x$ are 0 and 1.

The zeroes of $5^x-3\cdot4^x+3\cdot3^x-2^x$ are 0, 1, and 2.

The zeroes of $6^x-4\cdot5^x+6\cdot4^x-4\cdot3^x+2^x$ are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

The zeroes of $7^x - 5\cdot6^x+10\cdot5^x-10\cdot4^x+5\cdot3^x-2^x$ are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

The zeroes of $8^x-6\cdot7^x+15\cdot6^x-20\cdot5^x+15\cdot4^x-6\cdot3^x+2^x$ are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

And so on.... Basically the pattern here is the base decreases by 1, and the coefficients are of the Pascal's triangle.

So, with infinite terms, this function produces  roots that are the integers. Unlike the trigonometric functions (such as $sin(\pi\cdot x)$ which has roots that are integers, including negative numbers) that have a constrained range between -1 and 1, these series of functions amplitude increases back and forth between the roots until the highest power overpowers the other terms, as can be seen in the image below:

> [image: Image of the functions]

Comment: So you want to prove that the only zeros of $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(k+2)^x$ are $x=0,1,2\dots n-1$, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, except the last term in the way you have stated turns out to be positive or negative, depending on number of terms; whereas, it should always be positive. 
Perhaps the sign doesn't matter since we are speaking of zeroes and multiplying whole expression by -1 wouldn't affect the zeroes.

Comment: It is easy to see that any integer $j$ s.t. $0 \le j \lt n$  is a root, since  $(k+2)^j$ is a polynomial function of $k$ of order $j \lt n$, therefore its $n^{\text {th}}$ backward difference  is zero.

Comment: maybe induction on $n$ may work for showing that these are the only zeros. This is true for $n=1$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(t) $ be any function defined over $[0,\infty)$. Its
[forward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) is a function defined over same domain by the equation:

$$\Delta f(t) = f(t+1) - f(t)$$
Notice when $f(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, $\Delta f(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1$ (or zero if $f(t)$ is a constant polynomial).
Apply forward difference $n$ times, we find

$$\Delta^nf(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}f(t+k)$$

vanishes whenever $f(t)$ is a polynomial with $\deg f(t) < n$.

Substitute $f(t)$ by $(t+2)^x$, we obtain:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}(k+2)^x = 0
\quad\text{ at }\quad x = 0,\ldots, n-1.\tag{*1}$$

This means your equation has at least $n$ solutions in $x$.

The sort of function on LHS of $(*1)$ is called Dirichlet polynomial.
In 1883, Laguerre has proved a theorem${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$:

> **Generalized Descartes' rule of signs**
>
> Given a Dirichlet polynomial $P(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_j b_j^x$ where
> $a_j, b_j \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies:
> $$ a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n \ne 0,\quad\text{ and }\quad b_0 > b_1  > \cdots > b_n > 0$$ If $N$ is the number of sign changes in the coefficients $a_j$, then the number of real roots of $P(x)$ is bounded by $N$.

It is easy to see the sum you have has exactly $n$ sign changes. This means it has at most $n$ solutions. Since we have located $n$ solutions
for the problem, that's all the solutions it has.

**Notes/Refs**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - For a modern introduction to this subject, I'll recommned

  G.J.O Jameson, *Counting zeros of generalized polynomials: Descartes' rule of signs and Laguerre's extensions*, (Math. Gazette 90, no. 518 (2006), 223-234).

  An online copy can be found [here](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Ejameson/zeros.pdf).

Comment: If your proof is right, then the following formula for the power series not involving Bernoullie numbers is correct and has finite terms:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^x =1+\frac{2^x}{1!}(n-1)+\frac{3^x-2^x}{2!}(n-1)(n-2)+\frac{4^x-2\cdot 3^x+2^x}{3!}(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+\frac{5^x-3\cdot4^x+3\cdot3^x-2^x}{4!}(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+...$



And the formula terminates to finite terms since the coefficients have the zeroes as proved above by you.

Comment: @PriteshPatel Your expression is valid. Let $L$ by the left-shift operator on functions $$f(t) \mapsto Lf(t) = f(t+1)$$
You have $\Delta = L - 1$. Rewrite RHS in terms of $L$, you will find it equals to LHS. $$\begin{align}
{\rm RHS} &= 1 + \left.\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\Delta^{k-1} (t+2)^x\right|_{t=0}
= 1 + \left.\frac{ (1+\Delta)^{n-1} - 1}{\Delta} (t+2)^x\right|_{t=0}\\
&= 1 + \left.\frac{L^{n-1}-1}{L-1}(t+2)^x\right|_{t=0}
= 1 + \left.\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2} L^\ell(t+2)^x\right|_{t=0}
= 1 + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}(\ell+2)^x\\
&= {\rm LHS}
\end{align}$$